# Get a dynamic table td value using jquery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

my code

```
<table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr  class="md-bg-blue-grey-200">
        <th width="11%">Sl. No.</th>
        <th>State Name</th>            
        <th>District Name</th>            
    </tr>    
    </thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($district_name as $district_names){?>
    <tr>            
        <td><input type="radio" name="district_id" value="<?php echo $district_names['district_id']?>"  style="margin-left: 10px" checked>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $district_names['state']?></td>
        <td id="district_name"><?php echo $district_names['district']?></td>

    </tr><?php }?>

</tbody>
</table>
   <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 100px;">
  <a href="javascript:Setvalues()" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right"  
          style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="selectDistrict()">Select</a>
</div>
</div>
```

this is my function when i select a row this function has call.

```
<script>            
        function selectDistrict() {
            district_id = $('input[name=district_id]:checked').val();
            district_name 
            =$('#datatable').find("#district_name").eq(2).html();                             
            opener.district_select(district_id,district_name);              
            window.close();
        }
    </script>
```

I want to get district name column value but it shows undefined,how to get district name from this table.

Comment: use class instead of ID..ID should be unique on context

Comment: THAT: `.find("#district_name").eq(2)` doesn't make sense, because you can't have multiple elements in the DOM with the same ID. That's invalid html - Use class

Comment: i use class instead of id but it will return same value for all time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below code

```
district_name = $('input[name=district_id]:checked').parent().parent().find("td:eq(1)").text();
```

instead of

```
district_name = $('#datatable').find("#district_name").eq(2).html();
```

Comment: you can also use   $('input[name=district_id]:checked').closest('td').next('td').text()